# How to remove telegram's secondary account

Tags: telegram

Telegram has multiple accounts feature and you can follow the [guide here](https://beebom.com/how-use-multiple-accounts-telegram-messenger/) on how to enable it.

The problem is I can add a new account, but can't find any button or option to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open that account.
2. Go to Settings.
3. Tap on three dots in the upper right corner.
4. Log out.

Comment: Wow .. hidden place just to log out. Thanks btw